# Evaluating the sum of sines where the sum of the arguments is zero

Tags: trigonometry

I stumbled upon a problem which I can't seem to solve on my own or with the help of existing literature (maybe I can't find it). However, we know that the sum of two sines is zero is the sum of the arguments is zero. Since, if $a_1+a_2=0$ , then
$$ \sin(a_1)+\sin(a_2) = \sin(a_1)+\sin(-a_1) = \sin(a_1)-\sin(a_1) = 0 $$
This defines the base case, should we proceed with induction. However what happens for $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i =0$ is still unclear for me.

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n \sin(a_i) = 0$ does not hold for general n. Since for $n=3$ we see $$\sin(a_1)+\sin(a_2)+\sin(a_3) = \sin(a_1)+\sin(a_2) + \sin(-a_1-a_2) = \sin(a_1)+\sin(a_2)-\sin(a_1+a_2)$$ and this is not zero for all $a_1+a_2+a_3=0$ as the sine is not linear.
 But is there anything to say such that we can simplify this expression (knowing that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 0$)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_{i=1} a_i = 0$, then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sin(a_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sin(a_i) - \sin\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i \right)$$
But that's as "simple" as it gets.  You could expand the last sine into an expression in terms of $\sin(a_i)$ and $\cos(a_i)$, but it doesn't really get simpler.